# Play Form mapping for a list of trait instances

Tags: playframework

I have some classes that implement a trait Info and a UserData class that has a list of Info. An element in the list could be an instances of such classes (e.g. DriverInfo, TaskerInfo). Now, I want to create a play form for UserData, how do I do the mapping? I am mostly stuck at the List[Info]. I added the list to avoid creating 2 instances of UserData given that a user can fill out both forms.

`case class DriverInfo(licensePlate: String, maker: String, carType: String, model: String, yearOfModel: String, engine: String) extends Info`

`case class TaskerInfo(primaryService: String, otherServices: List[String], id: String, idType: String) extends Info`

`case class UserData(name: Option[String], firstName: String, lastName: String, info: List[Info])`

Here is what I have so far but it's not working. 

`val driverForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> optional(nonEmptyText),
      "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> email.verifying(maxLength(250)),
      "password" -> nonEmptyText.verifying(minLength(6)),
      "info" -> list(
        mapping(
          "licensePlate" -> nonEmptyText,
          "maker" -> nonEmptyText,
          "carType" -> nonEmptyText,
          "model" -> nonEmptyText,
          "yearOfModel" -> nonEmptyText,
          "engine" -> nonEmptyText)(DriverInfo.apply)(DriverInfo.unapply)))(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply))`

Comment: You can't use `optional` with `nonEmptyText`